# Trouble converting simple SQL to Linq

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm pretty stuck on converting this to LINQ:

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(1) AS Registrations, 
 YEAR(Join_date) AS Year, 
 MONTH(Join_date) AS Month
FROM tblForumAuthor
GROUP BY YEAR(Join_date), MONTH(Join_date)
ORDER BY Year, Month
```

It's just a simple report, but I can't work out how to do the group by's and counts as the select new.  I've only managed this pathetic attempt:

```
var q = (from c in db.tblForumAuthors 
         select new {Year = c.Join_date.Year, 
                     Month = c.Join_date.Month, 
                     Registrations = });
```

Comment: Just FYI, typo @ Year = c.Join_date.Month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var results = db.tblForumAuthors.GroupBy(r => new {Year = r.Join_date.Year, Month =  r.Join_date.Month})
                .Select(g => new {Registrations = g.Count(),  g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month})
                .OrderBy(r => r.Year)
                .ThenBy(r => r.Month)
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to make red squiggly lines though ` 'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,tblForumAuthor>' does not contain a definition for 'Year' and no extension method 'Year' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,tblForumAuthor>'`

Comment: see my answer above, in second line g.Year should be g.Key.Year

Comment: Super thanks!  You have an invalid semicolon btw though,  but seems to work great otherwise :D

Comment: @Tom I didn't see @valipour's answer but our answers are pretty much the same. I was missing `.Key` in the query. I have edited the answer or just refer to the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.tblForumAuthors
.GroupBy(c => new {c.Join_date.Month, c.Join_date.Year})
.OrderBy(g => g.Key.Year).ThenBy(g => g.Key.Month)
.Select(g => new
{
    Registrations = g.Count(),
    Year = g.Key.Year
    Month = g.Key.Month
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from c in db.tblForumAuthors 
group c by new {month = t.Join_Date.Month, year = t.Join_Date.Year} 
into g select new {month = g.Key.month, year = g.Key.year, count = g.Count()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipped to the post.... but this should do the trick. Notice how you can group by multiple fields by using an anonymous type. The properties of the group are available through the `Key` property of the grouping. Not sure if this will produce `Count(1)`, though. IIRC it will be `Count(*)`.

```
from c in db.tblForumAuthors
group c by new { c.Join_date.Year, c.Join_date.Month } into g
orderby g.Year, g.Month
select new {
    Registrations = g.Count(),
    g.Key.Year,
    g.Key.Month
};
```

Comment: Thanks!  Appreciate it but it doesn't compile `'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,tblForumAuthor>' does not contain a definition for 'Year' and no extension method 'Year' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,tblForumAuthor>' could be found`

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, you were missing the `Key` property. My query should have compiled from the C# compiler in my head....

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet there are better ways to do it, but here's one.

If the table had two fields defined like this:

```
tblForumAuthor
==========================
Join_Date    date
Name         nvarchar(50)
```

You could get a report of the number of people joining in each Month+Year combo like this:

```
var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

var report =
    from a in db.tblForumAuthors
    group a by new {Year = a.Join_Date.Year, Month = a.Join_Date.Month}
    into g
    select new
               {
                   Year = g.Key.Year,
                   Month = g.Key.Month,
                   Registrations = g.Count()
               };

foreach( var item in report)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Year + " " + item.Month + " " + item.Registrations);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is more like this - sorry don't have ability to test it

```
var results = from r in tblForumAuthorm 
group r by r.Join_date into  
select new { Year =r.Join_Date.Year, Month = r.join_date.month };
```

Comment: this is wrong! you are grouping by the whole date including day, hour, second ,...